# All intents disappeared in API.ai agent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a few agents in my account and all the intents for 3 just disappeared!!! I also see a popup on the bottom right saying "You do not have rights for this operation"

Please help - how do I get my intents back AND ensure this never happens again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you logged in using the wrong google account? I have to 'register' multiple times a day at the moment.

If you have an old Account (pre-Google) you can "Restore your access" on the right side of the [login screen](https://console.api.ai/api-client/#/login).

Also you may want to backup your intents. -> Settings -> Export and Import -> Export as Zip

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's an authentication problem related to https://discuss.api.ai/t/keep-getting-logged-out-and-have-to-re-authenticate-my-google-account/8890

Logout and re-authenticate. They will come back.